# List users in a dropdown for login

Tags: php, users, login

I have a loginscript that works. Now I want to expand the login functions with a dropdown filled with all users.

This is the login:

```
<div class="login-form">  
<?php 
    $login  = (isset($_GET['login']) ) ? $_GET['login'] : 0;
    if ( $login === "failed" ) {  
        echo '<p class="login-msg"><strong>ERROR:</strong> users/pass doesn't match</p>';  
    } elseif ( $login === "empty" ) {  
        echo '<p class="login-msg"><strong>ERROR:</strong> user/pass empty</p>';  
    } elseif ( $login === "false" ) {  
        echo '<p class="login-msg"> logged out.</p>';  
    }  
?>
<?php  
    $args = array(  
        'redirect' => get_bloginfo('url'),   
        'id_username' => 'user_login',  
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',  
        'remember'    => false,
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Login' ),
        )   
    ;?>  
    <?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>  
</div>
```

With the help of the WP-codex I created the following:

```
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
    echo '<select>';
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        echo '<option value="'. esc_html( $user->user_login ).'">' . esc_html( $user->user_login ) . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

This gives me all the users by login name.

The only thing I can't figure out is how to let the drop-down be the login part.

Hope it's something small!

M.

---------------------- UPDATE ----------------------

So this happend:

```
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename' );
$return = ' ';
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) 
    {
        $login = $user->user_login;
        $return .= '<option value="'.$login.'">' . $login . '</option>';
    }
```

This returns the values in a variable.
<del>I use the variable in the `$args` like this.</del>

```
id_username' => '<select>'.$return.'</select>',
```

<del>The problem is that the `wp_login_form` expects an `<input>` element and not an `<select>` element.</del>
This is stupid. It only adds the value to the id of the element..... Do'h!!!

I found that the  is hardcoded in the form. Can I change this?

Comment: regardless of the question, this is just a bad idea to help an attacker know which are the users it should try to attack. Security by obscurity is usually a fail, but it doesn't mean you have to make things easier to the potential attacker.

Comment: I know... But that was indeed not my question!